# How to built editable drop down list in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

```
 <div class="groupListEntryField handle">
 <% String sourceFieldName = rawGroupData.getRawSourceField(); %>
 <select class="config_el_width_150" id="selectField<%=groupNr %>"  onchange="changeGroupField(<%=groupNr %>)">
 <% for(String virtualField : rawGroupData.getRawAllVirtualField()){ %>
 <option value="<c:out value="<%=virtualField %>" />"  <%if(virtualField.equals(fieldName)){%>selected="selected"<%} %> ><c:out value="<%=virtualField %>" /></option>
 <%} %>
 </select>
 <input type="hidden" value="<c:out value="<%=sourceFieldName%>" />"   id="multiAttributeField<%=groupNr %>" name="multiAttributeField<%=groupNr %>" />
 <%} %>
 </div>
```

I create a drop down list like above . I want an editable drop down list where the user can put custom input if he doesn't find any suitable options . How can i accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem last week. :) I used a JQuery plugin from [chakrabarty JQuery plugin](http://chakrabarty.com/pp_editable_dropdown.html). From this, I figured out that all it needs is to tag one of the option fields, and it'll put it in. I'm assuming you're doing something like a form?